# Executar função existente pelo método `executeScript` do selenium-webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando executar uma função no browser que já está definida, mas a mesma é marcada como `undefined`.

Executei o seguinte código para reproduzir o problema:

```
const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver")
const driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build()

driver.navigate().to("http://localhost/site")
driver.sleep(3000)

const code = `console.log(window.sayHello)`
const logCode = `console.log("${code}")`

driver.executeScript(logCode)
driver.executeScript(code)
```

Quando tentei executar o mesmo código - `console.log(window.sayHello)` - diretamente no navegador ainda aberto, o mesmo retornou a função desejada, como na imagem:

[image: Log no navegador]

---

**EDITADO**

Este parece ser um bug específico com o driver do firefox, pois com o chrome funcionou. Acredito que a variável `window` esteja sendo [sobrescrita](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/firefox-driver/js/firefoxDriver.js#L241), porém não consegui reescrever a mesma com a `window` original.

Comment: Estás a encapsular duas vezes, é isso que queres? `driver.executeScript(console.log("console.log(window.sayHello)"))`? Não será que queres: `driver.executeScript(code);` somente?

Comment: @Sergio a primeira linha apenas exibe o código que será executado

Comment: O `. executeScript` faz log do conteúdo ou do retorno? testa `console.log('foo');`, dá `foo` ou `undefined`?

Comment: @Sergio editei o código da pergunta para tentar deixá-la mais simples. Basicamente, o primeiro comando `executeScript` apenas exibe o código que será executado na segunda chamada.